# VB6 Errors on old application

Tags: vb6

So I recently got the opportunity to recreate a very old application (20 years old) in C#,
the application is written in VB6, the original programmer has got Parkinson Disease therefor cannot do the conversion.

On His computer the application works fine no errors, When I start it up on my computer I just recieve an error that says library not found, so I figured out that 'StrConv' is giving the problem, if I put VBA.StrConv it then works but its through the WHOLE application, what Can I do to fix this, I already tried visual studio 2008 to convert to vb.net, but it fails so I decided to run the application and do piece by piece conversions, it would have been easier if it was in VB.net but thats life nothing comes easy :P

Found this link
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?451560-Classic-VB-What-does-this-error-mean-and-how-do-I-fix-it#noref

Will update the question when I get home and can actually see which references are missing

About 10 MISSIN references has been fixed, I only need the folowing

Adobe 3D Utility Type Library
(C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\A3DUtility.exe)

AdsSecurity 2.5 Type Library
(C:\Windows\System32\AdsSecurity.dll)

PDFPrevHndlrShim 1.0 Type Library
(C:\Program Files\Reader 11.0\Reader\pdfprevhndlrshim.dll)

Comment: can u provide detailed error log?

Comment: The only error I get is unrelated Highlighting of functions and the error
Compile Error:
Can't find project or library

Comment: highlighted functions in VB6 may be misleading. I've had a case where compiler would highlight a line of code that was not responsible for the error. So my advice is, try to fix the missing libraries issue and go from there. That being said, Crystal32.OCX is the Crystal reports library. You will need to install that in order for it to work. Or try and figure out how to install libraries separately.

Comment: Im downloading Crystal Reports now, hopefully that will solve some of the issues, I installed adobe 8 and some of the MISSING references dissapeared, but there are still a few left that seeks for adobe 8 or something from adobe 8

Comment: Alright I've solved everything except for Crystal Reports, where can I find the installation for Crystal32.OCX, I did download Crystal Reports 2008, however the library didn't come with it

Comment: Managed to fix Crystal.OCX see my updated question